# How-to make the admin area mobile friendly

Tags: admin, wp-admin, mobile, responsive

Currently the admin-UI is a no-go for mobile browsers. Therefore I'm searching for a plugin that makes the back-end/admin-UI accessible and a little more friendly for mobile devices.

Features, the plugin should have:

- Not outdated
- Not reliant on some 3rd party service

**Important** It's *not (!)* about a front-end Theme.

Short list of plugins that are outdate (will edit later)

- [iPhone / Mobile Admin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobileadmin/) - outdated
- [WPTouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) - not for admin UI

Thanks!

Comment: What specifically are you looking to see more functional? What model phone(s) are you using?

Comment: @TheZMan An accessible interface. One that floats the contents. Currently the admin bar won't zoom if you zoom, successfully preventing any click on a mobile display. The same goes for nearly any UI element as they're too small and zooming is an epic horror story.

Comment: What model phone are you using? Reason why I'm asking is there is work going on right now with a responsive admin for tablets and someone (*cough cough*) may be able to get some work in for mobile phones as well. http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/team-update-tableteers/

Comment: @TheZMan Thanks. I already recognized your avatar at trac :) I'm using an iPhone4G (no "s"). Point is that I hoped there's something out there for _"all"_ devices, not only for the fruit sorts of _smart_ phones. Btw: Links don't exceed comment lenght if put into rect. & round brackets - `[text](link)`.

Comment: I 110% agree .. no "fruity" limitations :) as for the link deal, duly noted thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have privileges to make comments, so goes as an answer... Two years ago I tested some App (maybe Automattic's) in my iphone3g (no "s") and it was ok... and surely there shall be some actual one's around... But, my comment is: this question is the bare bone for a business plan of the next *Premium-WordPress-Full-Featured-and-Cool* plugin around :)

Comment: Have you tried the mobile apps? There are WordPress Apps for most mobiles out there

Comment: I tried the default one. But honestly: If you're only allowed to publish `post` types without any of all those extras (custom meta data), what is it worth then?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, [but it may be the ticket.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-admin/)

This one has been updated a little more recently [JUIZ smart mobile admin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/juiz-smart-mobile-admin/)

Comment: Aside from some minor drawbacks (menu not really working, jquery ui problems), this works not that bad +1. Thanks.